# how to run multiple flash files in a loop in html using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i am having 4 flash files in .swf format, they are playing  in a loop,  1 after the other, for n no of times..

here's my code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>test page</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        var i=1;
        var restartTime = 10700; //in milliseconds
        function stopSwf()
        {           
        i=i+1;
        swfobject.removeSWF("swfLoop");
        startSwf();            
        }

        function startSwf() 
        {
          if(i==5)
         {
         i=1;
         }
          $("body").append("<div id='swfLoop'></div>");
          var flash = i+".swf";
          swfobject.createSWF({data:flash, width:900, height:400}, null, "swfLoop");
          setTimeout('stopSwf()', restartTime);
          }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="startSwf()">
</body>
</html>
```

my problem is, the above code is working fine in all browsers, except IE...

can any one help me in making this work in IE

thanks

**shameer ali shaik**

Comment: Do you use any flash <-> javascript communication? You should send events like "video stopped, give me another one" and process it on javascript (load next one).

Comment: ya, you can see in above code, that i am stopping the video after a particular time period & i am restarting the video.. the stop and start functions you can see in the above code...

Comment: @fliespl I did not realize you could communicate from flash to javascript.. now i have to look that up :) You could also try Local Connection with your flash files. This is a method of making flash files communicate. Essentially flash file one could complete and tell flash file two to start playing and so on..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your question I have already read an answer which regards to this [swf object](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/). It is an js object which will give the functions regarding to your problem

Comment: I believe Vivek is on the right path SWFObject is an open source javascript library which makes manipulating SWF files super easy. It also makes backup content for mobile users super easy. The website has tutorials on how to use the library as well as template downloads.